# Issues revolving adding NPM to my PATH

Tags: macbook-pro, big-sur

I am using BigSur OS on my MacBook. I want to start with typescript but when I tried add NPM to my PATH via terminal it did not work. What I am trying to do is add NPM to the PATH of my computer and do not know if I am doing the right thing. I have Node.js downloaded and NPM is also downloaded.

What I entered is as follows:

```
sudo npm install -g PACKAGE
```

The result being:

```
E404 (A bunch of 404 errors, saying it cannot find the package.)
```

[image: This image includes the result of the command I entered.]

Comment: How did you install `npm`?

Comment: @MarcWilson I downloaded node but that didnt work so I tried Brew.

Comment: And didn't follow the installation instructions since it's not on your `$PATH.`